# How to check if a div is active using an npc in game

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Is there a way to check if a div is active using a NPC in a Pokemon game? The main dev is inactive and I'm a staff member in the game. People are continually abusing a bug.

`````
if (tradeWindowDiv && tradeWindowDiv.style.display !== 'none') {
    // The trade window is active
    dialog.talk('Trade window is active!');
} else {
    // The trade window is not active
    dialog.talk('Trade window is not active.');
}````
`````

Comment: what happens to the div when clicked ? is it a modal ? is there any classes being added tot he div on click like "class =" trade-window is--active" ?